# Axios Interceptors: block access to particular pages

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I am trying to block users from accessing personal account pages when they are not authorised. Right now Axios interceptors watch for an error response status and if it's 401 which means that a user is not authorised to see those pages, it redirect the user to the login page. Like this:

```
axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(null, (error) => {
  if (error.response.status === 401) {
    if (router.history.current.fullPath.includes('profile')) {
      router.replace({
        path: '/login',
      });
    }
    this.$cookie.delete('token');
  }
  if (error.response.status === 404) {
    router.push({ name: 'error' });
  }
  if (error.response.status === 500) {
    router.push({ name: 'server_error' });
  }
  return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

It works as I want but I can see weird behaviour in the interface though. In the moment when I, being unauthorised, am trying to access the page, I can see it for a second or less and then I am redirecting to the login page. Is it possible to get rid of this? I want to be redirected straight to the login page without seeing a page which must be blocked for access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise to use navigation guards : https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#per-route-guard

Example :

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/foo',
      component: Foo,
      beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
        if (!isLoggedIn()) {
          next({
            path: '/login'
          })
        } else {
          next()
        }
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it didn't work out for me. :( I get an empty page and the console says `can't read isLoggedIn of undefined`. This method returns token which I set after login or registration. And of course it is undefined as I delete the token after logout.

Comment: You should store the token in local storage. You can retrieve it in the `isLoggedIn` method like this : `localStorage.getItem(TOKEN)`  and then check if the token is null or expired.

Comment: I am using `vue-cookie` library for managing cookies. In that method I get the token (`VueCookie.get('token)`)but as I deleted this after logout, it returns `undefined`.

Comment: thank you very much. What sort of checking we can do in the method `isTokenExpired`?

Comment: I tried the updated solution but without checking if the token has expired or not. Still no success. The same error message `can't read isLoggedIn of undefined`. :(

Comment: You are using this npm package aren't you ? https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-cookie
I changed the `VueCookie.get` who doesn't seem to be correct with `this.$cookie.get` from the docs.
If you still have the error, can you tell me at which line?

Comment: You can use `VueCookie.get` and `this.$cookie.get` as well. I am having the same error and it is said `Cannot read property 'isLoggedIn' of undefined at beforeEnter`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191668/discussion-between-btl-and-olga-b).

Comment: This solution worked out. The problem was with accessing my method `isLoggedIn`.